# How to manage this problem in a multiplayer client-server game with Photon ?

Tags: unity, multiplayer, photon

Good day.

I'm developing my first simple game, a racing car, using Unity and Photon. 
In my game there are a function that generate random Bonus on random position each (for instance) 5 seconds.

The problem is that if I use RPC, each Peer connected generate a bonus each 5 seconds and send that bonus on other client connected . Results: if i have 5 clients, each clients generate 1 bonus each 5 seconds resulting in 25 bonus each 5 seconds.

So, i would like that ONLY the server generate bonus and send this bonus to each clients.

**In short: i don't know how to 'tell' unity and photon "If i am the server run this function, otherwise not"**

```
if (i am server )
   generate bonus
   instantieBonus on clients
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
if (PhotonNetwork.isMasterClient){
                generate bounds
                run RPC
   }
```

master client is the first player who joined the room .